# Fix matlab code with error

Tags: matlab, dimensions

I understand that there is an error with dimensions in line dr=(r-v*v/2)*dT . But I have little knowledge of Matlab. Help to fix it, please. The code is small and simple. Maybe someone will find time to look

```
 function [optionPrice] = upAndOutCallOption(S,r,v,x,b,T,dT)
    t = 0;
    dr=[];
    pert=[];
    while (t < T) & (S < b)
        t = t + dT;
        dr = (r - v.*v./2).*dT;
        pert = v.*sqrt( dT ).*randn();
        S = S.*exp(dr + pert);
    end
    if S<b
        % Within barrier, so price as for a European option.
        optionPrice = exp(-r.*T).* max(0, S - x);
    else
        % Hit the barrier, so the option is withdrawn.
        optionPrice = 0;
    end
    end
```

Call from another function of this kind:

`for k=1:amountOfOptions
[optionPrices(k)] = upAndOutCallOption(stockPrice(k)*o,riskFreeRate(k)*o,... volatility(k)*o, strike(k)*o, barrier(k)*o, timeToExpiry(k)*o, sampleRate(k)*o);
result(k) = mean(optionPrices(k));
end`

Therefore, any difficulties.

Comment: welcome to SO. we will not debug the code for you. please provide **smallest** possible examples that reproduces your error.

Comment: In Matlab it's easy do output the result of expression just dropping the `;` on the end, so adding `r` , `v` , `dT` in separate lines right before the erroneous line you've mentioned could help you out.

Comment: @pawel.boczarski better stil learn [how to debug a Matlab script](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html).

Comment: Did you define your variable 'o' before calling your function?

Comment: @Hwathanie yes of course.  o = ones(1, M); when M=1e4

Comment: The actual error message would be more helpful than "an error with dimensions".

Comment: @СултанГашимов I fear it is more or less impossible to find the error when the dimensions of your input is unknown. If all inputs would be scalar this code would likely run with out crashing, just to take an example. Follow the link to how to debug a Matlab script provided by [shai](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937835/fix-matlab-code-with-error#comment47998622_29937835). And sorry to be rude, but I am afraid staying silent until someone asks you to clarify or give an answer will not help here. You may for example want to explain why Shai's, IMO excellent option does not help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good that you know the problem is within `dr = (r - v.*v./2).*dT;`. The command itself has many possible problems which also related to `dimensions`:

1. Here you are doing element-wise multiplication (because of the `.*`) with matrices, which requires (in the case of your command) that `r` has the same number of rows AND columns as `v` (since because of element-wise, `v.*v/2` has the same size as `v`).
2. Moreover, it is unnecessary to do element-wise division with scalar number, that means there is no need to have `./2` in Matlab.
3. And, finally, since it's element-wise multiplication again, the matrix `(r - v.*v./2)` must also have the same number of rows and columns as matrix `dT`.

Check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/basic-matrix-operations.html) for more information about Matlab's matrix operations.